# Can software interrupt `int` instruction be used to trigger a hardware interrupt handler?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, interrupt

This might be a trivial question, but i cannot easily find an answer online.

Can the software interups `int` instruction (in Intel processors) be used to trigger any interrupt handler, including those that respond to hardware interrupts? If yes, is this used in practice?

Comment: Yes you can. No it isn't used because the handler typically checks the device and then it will see it's an invalid interrupt.

Comment: @Jester: Do OSes not usually set up the IDT entry to stop user-space from actually invoking handlers with `int`?  They do that for exceptions like #DE (`int 0`).  Or do you just mean in theory if the OS was set up to allow it?

Comment: In theory, or in kernel I guess :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Intel `IA-32` and `x86-64` architectures, the [Interrupt Descriptor Table](https://wiki.osdev.org/Interrupt_Descriptor_Table) (IDT) has a Descriptor privilege level (DPL) field for each entry, which defines the CPU Privilege Levels (CPL) that are allowed to access that interrupt handler via the `INT` instruction (software interrupts). Hardware interrupts coming from devices ignore this mechanism.

The [Linux](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/understanding-the-linux/0596002130/ch04s04.html) operating system kernel initializes all the entries of the IDT while initializing the system. (I presume other operating systems do the same in their own fashion.)

The `INT` instruction allows a User Mode process to issue an interrupt signal that has an arbitrary vector ranging from 0 to 255. Therefore, initialization of the IDT must be done carefully, to block illegal interrupts and exceptions simulated by User Mode processes via `INT` instructions. This can be achieved by setting the DPL field of the IDT entry to `0` (this is [ring](https://wiki.osdev.org/Security#Rings) 0, i.e. kernel mode). If the process attempts to issue one of these interrupt signals, the control unit checks the CPL value against the DPL field and issues a [General Protection Fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_protection_fault) (interrupt vector number `13`).

In a few cases, however, a User Mode process needs to be able to issue a programmed exception. To allow this, it is sufficient to set the DPL field of the corresponding IDT entry to `3` (ring 3, i.e. userspace). The four Linux exception handlers associated with the vectors `3`, `4`, `5`, and `128` can be issued in User Mode because their IDT entries have the DPL field set to `3`. Therefore, the four assembly language instructions `INT3` (Breakpoint: interrupt number 3), `INTO` (Overflow: interrupt number `4`), `BOUND` (Bounds range exceeded: `INT 0x05`), and `INT 0x80` (for system calls) can be issued by User Mode processes.

The interrupt handlers for all other vectors are privileged and their corresponding `INT` instructions are considered privileged instructions that can only be executed by the kernel itself, running with CPL `0`. What I'm not sure of is whether, in practice, the kernel itself executes `INT` instructions to call various interrupt handlers.

Comment: A kernel *could* in theory use `int` to pre-empt itself at certain points, but there's near zero advantage to doing that vs. a cheap near `call` to a kernel function.  (Especially if we assume a monolithic kernel using a flat memory model.)  And significant performance downside.  I'm pretty sure Linux doesn't do it in any of the hand-written or inline asm parts for x86; when it wants other parts of the kernel to be able to do something, it defines a C function that other code can call.  I expect most modern kernels are like that.